# How are Rails instance variables passed to views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I have a controller like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @blog_post = BlogPost.find params[:id]
  end
end
```

In my view I can simply do this:

```
<%= @blog_post.title %>
```

I'm uncomfortable with magic. How is this achieved?

Comment: It seems standard with MVC programming. I would advice against declaring an instance variable within your view though.

Comment: Hi @meagar, I've dug around in ActionView renderer. I'm assuming it has something to do with the context, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: There's a book about how Rails does OOP wrong. It's called [Rails As She Spoke](http://railsoopbook.com/) and it does address this question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are instance variables in controllers made available to views in Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8528411/how-are-instance-variables-in-controllers-made-available-to-views-in-rails)

Comment: I downloaded and read Rails As She Is Spoke, what an excellent book, thanks for the recommendation!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Howcome an Instance variable @variable defined in the controller's action can be called from its views?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035103/howcome-an-instance-variable-variable-defined-in-the-controllers-action-can-be)

Answer (score 96, accepted):

When the view is being rendered, instance variables and their values are picked up from the controller and passed to the view initializer which sets them to the view instance. This is done using these ruby methods:

`instance_variables` - gets names of instance variables ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variables))
`instance_variable_get(variable_name)` - gets value of an instance variable ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get))
`instance_variable_set(variable_name, variable_value)` - sets value of an instance variable ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set))

Here is the Rails code:

Collecting controller instance variables ([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c5552a3dd28e35cce64462765cc41c5355db0f1/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb#L138-L145)):

```
def view_assigns
  hash = {}
  variables  = instance_variables
  variables -= protected_instance_variables
  variables -= DEFAULT_PROTECTED_INSTANCE_VARIABLES
  variables.each { |name| hash[name[1..-1]] = instance_variable_get(name) }
  hash
end
```

Passing them to the view ([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0c5552a3dd28e35cce64462765cc41c5355db0f1/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb#L84-L86)):

```
def view_context
  view_context_class.new(view_renderer, view_assigns, self)
end
```

Setting them in the view ([github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f817bb2c485d7363be104fd8a00b28c36a0adefc/actionpack/lib/action_view/base.rb#L177-L179)):

```
def assign(new_assigns) # :nodoc:
  @_assigns = new_assigns.each { |key, value| instance_variable_set("@#{key}", value) }
end
```

Comment: BTW, you can hold down SHIFT when selecting lines on github. I've upgraded your links.

Comment: mechanicalfish explained how this works, so it is clear that this is no 'magic' behind it; however I was uncomfortable about that mechanism too, as I consider it as breaking the encapsulation, and I found a gem that addresses this issue in a very clean manner: https://github.com/voxdolo/decent_exposure

Comment: This is an awesome answer, exactly what I was hoping for. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for cool answer. But I am really curious about where 'fragment caching' stands on this scenario? Do cached blocks causes calls on controller or not?

Comment: This is so great, thanks! How did you even find these code segments? What's your process for finding source code like this? That seems like the hard part and it's something I wish I were better at...because this seems like real understanding.

Answer (score -3):

The [decent_exposure](https://github.com/hashrocket/decent_exposure) gem is an alternative to Rails' standard controller instance variable behavior.  The readme has a good writeup about the issue.