# Return values from rails controller - confused Java programmer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, return-value

noobie rails question here. I read that the "last evaluated statement" in ruby gets returned without explicitly writing "return ...".
Following example (from this tutorial [Rails and Javascript](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html))

```
 class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end
```

Now in the html.erb they use it like this

```
<ul id="users">
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <%= render user %>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

So I dont have to explicitly return the instance variables, both of them (@users and @user) are available in my views.? Is that unique for instance variables or would it be possible with local variables too Im coming from Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instance variables are always available in the view. You do not need to return anything.

Here is a good explanation on how variables are passed from controller to view:

[How are Rails instance variables passed to views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855178/how-are-rails-instance-variables-passed-to-views)

Comment: Nice, great post with the link to the sources. I need to get used to all of the default behaviors and automatic stuff. Thanks!

Comment: And, yes, it is unique for instance variables. You won't be able to do the same with local variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
  @users = User.all
  @user = User.new
  user_detail = get_user_info(@users.last)
end
```

It's an action in controller, the instance variable initalized will be available in view. Just consider a case you have some method named `get_user_info`

```
def get_user_info(user)
  name = user.name
  email = user.email
end
```

user_detail will contain the value of email, the method above will return the last value as default.

Answer (score 0):

A controller method does not return values to your view. Instead it returns the rendered page to the browser where the request came from.
It is simply a convention that a controller automatically invokes a `render` call to a template of the same name.

You could write your controller method like this with the same behavior:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new

    return render 'index'
end
```

Since the last evaluated value is returned automatically, this is equivalent:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new

    render 'index'
  end
```

And since the controller calls render of the same name automatically, you can just remove it entirely (unless your template has a different name than your controller method)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end
```

---

It is considered bad practice to have too many instance variables in a controller, so you might want to call the render manually anyway and pass local variables like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    users = User.all
    user = User.new

    render 'index', :locals => { :all_users => users, :new_user => user }
  end
```

Access the locals in the frontend:

```
<ul id="users">
  <% all_users.each do |user| %>
    <%= render user %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```