# Instance Variables In The View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently started learning Ruby on Rails and came across something that confused me based on what I learned in Ruby. In The Rails Tutorial, the following code is used to retrieve all the users from the Model, and pass it on to the view:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  .
  .
  .
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end
  .
  .
  .
```

In the view:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= user.name %></td>
    <td><%= user.email %></td>
```

It was my understanding that instance variables cannot be accessed outside their class without accessor methods, but here the View can access @users. Why is that so? And why do we have to use an instance variable to loop through the users?

Comment: rails does this for you, take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855178/how-are-rails-instance-variables-passed-to-views

Comment: The way I see it, It's the same class since you're calling the variable from the view template of `users`.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct - you can't access an instance variable outside the class. The `@users` in your controller isn't actually the exact same instance variable as the `@users` in your view. For practical purposes it is, but what actually happens is that Rails, behind the scenes, will look at all the instance variables you have in your controller, and copy them across to your view. This is a convenience thing - rails just does this to save you having to worry about it.

It's worth noting, not all frameworks take this approach. So in some frameworks, you have to explicitly say which variable you want to make available to the view. If rails did this, some code might look like:

```
def index

  @users = User.all
  first_user = User.first

  set_for_view(first_user, :the_first_user)
end
```

Only the `set_for_view` method would set variables available to be used in your view. So, `@users` would NOT be available in the view (doesn't matter that it's an instance variable), and likewise, `first_user` WOULD be available - doesn't matter that it is NOT an instance variable, as long as it's passed in to `set_for_view`. And in this example, `first_user` would be available in the view under the variable name `the_first_user` - since that's the name we passed in the second parameter to `set_for_view`.

Rails, as a framework, opts for 'convention over configuration', and does a lot of magic under the hood to save you having to write extra code like this. Rails just says "anything instance variable you set in your controller, we'll copy it over and make it available in your view - that way you don't have to worry about it".

Some people like this about rails, others criticise it. Takes all types!

Comment: Note you can also explicitly pass local variables to the view in Rails if you have concerns about using ivars.
`render 'view', locals: {user: @user}`

Answer (score 1):

So,

Ruby on Rails is framework, where **Convention over Configuration** rule is really important. Behind the scenes, Rails matches proper controller actions with views files, which have the same name eg. `index` action will be matched with `index.html.erb`.

This special connection enables Rails to use in views instance variables, which are set in particular index.
As you can see instance variable `@users` is available in view file, but any other is not.