# How does rails pass instance variable from controller to views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instance-variables

I created a simple rails app in rails using scaffolding method for `restaurants`.

This is the show and edit controller method for `restaurants_controller.rb`. Notice how they are just blank methods:

```
  # GET /restaurants/1
  # GET /restaurants/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /restaurants/1/edit
  def edit
  end
```

This is `restaurants/show.html.erb`:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<%= image_tag @restaurant.image_url %>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Address:</strong>
  <%= @restaurant.address %>
</p>
...
```

and `restaurants/edit.html.erb`:

```
<h1>Editing Restaurant</h1>

<%= render 'form', restaurant: @restaurant %>

<%= link_to 'Show', @restaurant, class: "btn btn-link" %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', restaurants_path, class: "btn btn-link" %>
```

Here is my question: my current understanding (could be wrong) is that we define the instance variable, in this case, `@restaurant` in `restaurant_controllers.rb`, and Rails automatically connects the variables defined in the controller to views. For example, index method in restaurant controller:

```
def index
  @restaurants = Restaurant.all
end
```

when I call `@restaurants` in `index.html.erb`, Rails brings up `@restaurants` from index method to be used in `views`.

Where does rails get the `@restaurant` instance variable in `show.html.erb` and `edit.html.erb` from even though `show` and `edit` method in `restaurants_controller.rb` are empty methods? I am using Rails 5.

Comment: Do you have a `before_action :set_restaraunt` in your controller?

Comment: Are you using CanCan with `load_and_authorize_resource` in the controller?

Comment: You may wanna know "Why can I access instance vars I defined in the controller?", https://stackoverflow.com/a/18855824/5005466

Answer (score 0):

So rails acheives this by applying this to generated scaffolds

```
class TestsController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_test, only: [:show, :edit, :new, :update, :destroy]

 private

  def set_test
    @test = Test.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

that dose the same as adding

`@test = Test.find(params[:id])` to every action if you don't need to..

that then, sets the instance variable on the actions defined by the before_action

im no rails pro, so there may be a much better answer to this, but i have learned to not question "rails magic".

Comment: and you can do the same if you generate your own MVC and apply the same practice above.