# Rails 5 - Displaying error messages

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

So I currently have user account creation and login working. I want to be able to display any error or validation messages when the user types in a field that does not satisfy the validation requirements I have placed for the models. From some examples, I see that people render a partial called "_errors.html.erb" that is within the shared folder. However, when I tried this, it did not work for me and I believe that is the case because I am using Rails 5. I have tested a bit on the "_errors.html.erb" and I believe that the "any?" part of the if statement does not work as intended.

Does anyone know a way to display errors or validations on the view when the user types in an incorrect value for a field? Thanks!

_errors.html.erb

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
    <div class="panel panel-warning errors">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h5><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></i> Found errors while saving</h5>
      </div>

      <ul class="panel-body">
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

User - new.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">TimeTracker</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

  <div class="loginContainer" align="center">
    <h1 align="center"><b>Sign Up</b></h1>

    <%= form_for @user do |u| %>
        <div class="container">

          <%= render 'shared/errors', object:@user %>


          <label><b>First Name</b></label>
          <%= u.text_field :first_name, placeholder: 'First Name' %>

          <label><b>Last Name</b></label>
          <%= u.text_field :last_name, placeholder: 'Last Name' %>

          <label><b>Username</b></label>
          <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email Address' %>
          <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required> -->

          <br><label><b>Password</b></label>
          <%= u.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password' %>
          <!--<input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required> -->

          <br><label><b>Confirm </b></label>
          <%= u.password_field :password_confirmation, placeholder: 'Confirm Password' %>

          </br>
          <br>
          <%= u.submit 'Sign Up', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>

          </br>
        </div>
    <% end %>

  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

User Sessions - new.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Time Tracker</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="loginContainer" align="center">

  <h1 align="center"><b>Log In</b></h1>

  <%= form_for @user_session do |u| %>
      <div class="container">


        <%= render 'shared/errors', object:@user_session %>

        <label><b>Email</b></label>
        <%= u.text_field :email, placeholder: 'Email Address' %>
        <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required> -->

        <br>
        <label>
          <b>Password</b>
        </label>
        <%= u.password_field :password, placeholder: 'Password' %>
        <br>

        <!-- Feature not working, left in there just in case -->
        <!--<%= u.label 'Remember me' %> -->
        <!--<%= u.check_box :remember_me %> -->

        <%= u.submit 'Login', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>


      </div>
  <% end %>


  <div class="container" style="background-color:#D3D3D3">
    <%= link_to 'Forgot your password?', new_password_reset_path %>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

User Model

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :activities, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy

  acts_as_authentic

    validates :first_name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1}
    validates :last_name, presence: true, length: {minimum: 1}
    validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true, length: {minimum: 5}
    validates :password, :confirmation => true, length: {minimum: 4}
    validates :password_confirmation, presence: true

    def deliver_password_reset_instructions
      reset_perishable_token!
     PasswordResetMailer.reset_email(self).deliver_now
    end
  end
```

**EDIT - 04/19 - 8:30 PM**

Sample blank submission with just a name and other fields left blank.

> Processing by UsersController#create as HTML   Parameters:
>   {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"9HH1kH8cPNfjO2LnsLHRSEATs0g5d95jAHUYX8ZXhF7cz335Vg0G8jvtJeCdPHnqYyCtuVDV9frZmdo1z2b1wg==",
>   "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Ben", "last_name"=>"", "e mail"=>"",
>   "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"},
>   "commit"=>"Sign Up"}
>
> (0.0ms)  BEGIN   User Exists (3.5ms)  SELECT 
>   1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) LIMIT
>   $2  [["email", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS
>   one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."persistence_token" = $1 LIMIT $2 
>   [["persistence_token",
>   "58253c420dea482caa7cc457f7a6d4f9e5c9ea5008c30d82c2da9cfc8a3cdb189
>   5cfb05b75797f54959fb7f621a9e223073e8721bf75df60f6bb72387d469eee"],
>   ["LIMIT", 1]]
>
> User Exists (0.5ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"
>   WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", ""], ["LIMIT", 1]]
>   (2.0ms)  ROLLBACK

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = 'Account created'
      redirect_to home_path
    else
      flash[:notice] ='ERROR: Account was not created'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

User Sessions Controller

```
class UserSessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @user_session = UserSession.new
  end

  def create

    @user_session = UserSession.new(user_session_params)

    @user_session.remember_me = true

    if @user_session.save
      flash[:success] = 'Welcome back'
      redirect_to :back
    else
      flash[:notice] = 'Failed to log in'
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  def destroy
    current_user_session.destroy
    flash[:success] = 'Goodbye'
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private

  def user_session_params
    #params.require(:user_session).permit(:email,:password,:remember_me)
    params.require(:user_session).permit(:email,:password)

  end

end
```

Fixed User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = 'Account created'
      redirect_to home_path
    else
      flash[:notice] ='ERROR: Account was not created'
      render 'users/new'
    end
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was that in order to make the `@user` instance variable available to the view, you need to render rather than redirect.

When you redirect, you're sending a response to the user that says, "Hit me up again". When the *subsequent* request comes in, the action gets executed a *second* time. The `@user` instance variable was available the first time the action was executed, but based on the logic in the action, doesn't get populated with errors on the second time (why would it).

See [How are Rails instance variables passed to views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855178/how-are-rails-instance-variables-passed-to-views).

---

The issue could be at any of the following steps:

1. **The request may not be getting routed to the controller you expect**. Try looking at the server logs. When you start your server with `rails server` or `rails s` in the console, that window will show all incoming requests, and it'll show the controller + action that get hit. For example:

Example from my test app:

```
code/blog [master●] » rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.0.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Puma starting in single mode...
* Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.4.1-p111), codename: Sassy Salamander
* Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
Use Ctrl-C to stop
Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2017-04-19 17:55:42 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by UncategorizedPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendering uncategorized_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered uncategorized_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (1.4ms)
  Rendered partials/_navbar.html.erb (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 293ms (Views: 291.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Here you can see that the request is `GET /`, and it hits the `home` action of `UncategorizedPagesController`. To be doubly sure, you could add a `puts "hits this action"` in your controller action, and look for "hits this action" in your server logs.

2. **The form(s) may not be sending the payload you expect them to be sending to the server**. Try checking the [`params`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) hash in your controller. As the link explains, the `params` hash will contain the data you submitted in your form. Ie. `params[:email]` might be `foo@bar.com` in your controller. You can test this by adding `puts params` to your controller action and checking the server logs after you hit the corresponding route.
3. **The validations may not be behaving as you expect them to**. To test this, try using the console (in sandbox mode so it doesn't mess with your actual database) like so:

Console output:

```
$ rails console --sandbox
>> user = User.new(name: "", email: "mhartl@example.com")
>> user.valid?
=> false
>> user.errors.full_messages
=> ["Name can't be blank"]
```

You should also use unit tests to make sure your validations work as expected. See below for an example from the [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users#sec-user_validations)

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "name should be present" do
    @user.name = ""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end

  test "email should be present" do
    @user.email = "     "
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
end
```

4. **You may not be trigging validation to happen**. From the official [RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark):

> The following methods trigger validations, and will save the object to
>   the database only if the object is valid:
>
> - create
> - create!
> - save
> - save!
> - update
> - update!
>
> The bang versions (e.g.
>   save!) raise an exception if the record is invalid. The non-bang
>   versions don't: save and update return false, and create just returns
>   the object.

5. **Your controller logic may not be sending the user with errors back to the view**. To test this, print out the full `@user` in one of the `new.html.erb` files using any of the approaches mentioned in the [RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#view-helpers-for-debugging). `debug(@user)` is one option.
6. **You may not be referencing the right file in your attempt to render the `_errors.html.erb` partial**. To test this, try to render the partial with just a `hello world`.
7. **You may not be passing in the object to the partial properly**. To test this, try logging out your object from the view using any of the approaches mentioned in the [RailsGuide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#view-helpers-for-debugging). `debug(object)` is one option.

It seems that you are doing it properly though. From [the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/PartialRenderer.html):

> If you're not going to be using any of the options like collections or layouts, you can also use the short-hand defaults of render to render partials. Examples:

```
# Instead of <%= render partial: "account", locals: { account: @buyer } %>
<%= render "account", account: @buyer %>
```

Comment: For 3, I used sandbox mode and after creating user with just an email, valid returned to me false as expected and once I told it to give me the full  error messages, it gave me the correct ones regarding the validation errors.

For 4, I am mainly using the save method so I believe the validations should be triggered. Adding an exclaimation mark to the "save" will also give me the correct error page on which validation was violated.


For 6, the partial is rendering correctly as after I altered code of the partial to `<h1>test</h1>, the contents were displayed correctly when rendered.

Comment: For 1, 2, 5, and 7, I do not know how to test for those. I am fairly new to Rails so apologies for that. I used `debug(@user)` for 5 and placed it in the `new.html.erb' of the User views, it displayed some information that did not change after I submitted a blank form.

Comment: If you're new to Rails, Michael Hartl's [Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/) is awesome. So are the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/). I'll update the answer with clarifications for the rest.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now that you posted your Controller code - you're redirecting. If you `render` in the `else`, it should work. When you render, the `@user` instance variable is made available to the view. When you redirect, you're just telling the browser to hit the view again, the route gets hit, and the instance variable isn't available in the view. There's a lot of magic going on in Rails, and it can definitely be confusing. I'll look into it more for a better explanation.

Comment: I see that makes sense. So I imagine I'd need to add something like `render 'shared/errors', object: @user` to my else statement? Adding that exact statement throws me a template error so I figured I had to change it to `render 'shared/_errors', object: @user'` instead but that is throwing me an error that the object variable inside the partial is not defined but I thought I passed it with the code above?

Comment: You want to render the corresponding view. If you're following a typical RESTful design, the view that corresponds to `create` is `new`. The view that corresponds to `update` is `edit`. So, from the `create` action, `render :new` should work. Rails will see that it's the Users controller and will thus look for a view in `app/views/users/new.html.erb`, which you have ([Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)). From there, `@user` should be available, and you'll be passing it into the errors partial and rendering the errors from the partial.

Comment: Yeah I just figured that out. It works as expected thank you for the advice and help!

Comment: Sure. Glad I could help.

Comment: I updated my answer with the explanation plus a link to how instance variables get passed to views.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', object:@user %>
```

with:

```
<%= render 'shared/errors', object: u.object %>
```

Comment: Tried the change and I still couldn't get any errors to be displayed. I did a quick test by putting in `<h1>ERROR</h1>` in the "if statement" and that never showed up on my sign up page after I submitted a blank form. 

Just making sure, but I do not have any errors rendering the error partial. My main problem is that no errors are displaying after I render the partial.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your Users controller

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:success] = 'Account created'
      redirect_to home_path
    else
      flash[:notice] ='ERROR: Account was not created'
      render :new
    end
end
```

I had this exact problem in Rails 5, and this is what worked for me.